# Why does this code skip the if statements that set string variables?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I'm trying to make a project that asks some questions about a hotel visit and repeats the answers back, pretty simple. So far I have this for code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int df;
    int days; 
    string bed;
    string bn;

    cout << "Welcome to C++ Hotel, we have to ask you a few questions about your stay in order to give you the correct rate." << endl;
    cout << "First, what floor would you like to stay on? (We currently have rooms available from floors 2 to 12)" << endl;
    cin >> df;
    while (df > 12 && 2 < df){
        cout << "Sorry, but your answer is invalid, please enter a floor from 2 to 12." << endl;
        cin >> df;
    }
    cout << "Okay, we will register your room on floor " << df << "." << endl;
    cout << "Now, what type of bed will you be requesting during your visit? On floor " << df << " we currently have doubles, queens, or a suite." << endl;
    cin >> bed;
    while (bed != "d" && bed != "q" && bed != "s"){
        cout << "Sorry, but your answer is invalid, please choose between a double, queen or suite by entering either d, q, or s respectively." << endl;
        cin >> bed;
    } 

    if (bed == "d"){
        string bn = "double";
    } 
    if (bed == "q"){
        string bn = "queen";
    }
    if (bed == "s"){
        string bn = "suite";
    }
    cout << "Okay, your room will be on floor " << df << " with a " << bn << "     sized bed!" << endl;
}
```

I want the user to be able to input d, q or s for the double, queen or suite bed size option, but I also want to repeat what they have chosen at the end of the question, and it obviously sounds stupid if it says something along the lines of "you have chosen the d sized bed!"

So instead I made a few if statements that basically set a new string variable based on what the user inputs for the original bed variable. So if they put in a d for double, the bn variable is set to "double", then at the end the bn is called upon in the final cout.

However, the code seems to just skip over the 3 if statements completely, and at then end when the variable is called upon it is just blank, the code runs fine with no errors or warnings or anything, but I can't figure out why it just doesn't recognize the code, it seems okay to me?

Comment: `df > 12 && 2 < df` should be `df > 12 || df < 2`

Comment: @Dante:  If you suspect your program is skipping over code, you should put a `cout` statement there to print something (or even better use `cerr` or even better yet use a debugger and step through the code).

Comment: `df > 12 && 2 < df` is always false

Comment: `{` starts a new scope.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `string bn = "double";` with

```
bn = "double";
```

You are declaring another local `string` with name `bn` and setting it to some value and actual `bn` you intend to set remains unchanged.

Further reading: [Scope in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: Ah I see so because I already said it was a string in the beginning of the main I don't need to do so again. Thank you I'm still new to this, I'm not sure why it skips over it completely (or at least that is what it seems to be doing) but it works now! Thanks I'll remember this for the future.

Comment: Also make sure you read the recommended further reading and understand it. Anything you don't understand try to google it. Still if you don't understand make it a new question. And check the comment from M.M

Comment: It's not that it "skipped it". It's that you declared a new variable of the same name, local only to the if-block, assigned a string to it, and then that local variable got deleted as the code exited the if-block. There was no skipping; it's just that the code didn't do anything interesting! :)